# Bluehost-Premature end of headers in python script

Tags: python, cgi, bluehost

I have a website and I have 2 python cgi scripts in a cgi-bin folder under my website. Now everytime it tries to load either of these 2 python cgi scipts, server returns 500 error, and there's the premature end of errors infamous error.

So I tried something new. I made a very simple python cgi-script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "Hello World!"
```

I named this `hello_world.py`, put it in the cgi-bin with the other 2 python scripts, and I ran the following link: http://steap.co/cgi-bin/hello_world.py, and it amazingly returned "Hello World!".

This showed me that something was wrong with my python scripts, but I don't know what. This is my script:

**Steap.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
#Steam64 ID - 76561198041707719
import urllib
import cgi, cgitb
import itertools
import urllib2
import time
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, redirect
import requests
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
import sys

//code goes here

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<div id=\"phisher-users\"></br></br>"
print getFriendList(steeam)
print "</div>"
print "<div id=\"phisher-ids\" style=\"display: none;\">"
print grabPhisherIDs()
print "</div>"
```

And now when the server tried to load this script, I got some more information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Steap.py", line 9, in 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
[Sat Dec 06 09:58:07 2014] [error] [client 174.61.70.33] Premature end of script headers: Steap.py
```

Why is this happening? I custom installed python 2.7 in my website, and I used pip to all all the custom modules above (such as bs4, flask, etc.).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try running pip freeze command and see whether its showing bs4 or BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @TanveerAlam How do I do that?

Comment: Just go to command prompt and type `pip freeze` then press enter.

Comment: @TanveerAlam Ok I see `BeautifulSoup==3.2.1` and `beautifulsoup4==4.3.2`

Answer (score 0):

I have both `3.2.1` and `4.3.2` version of [**BeautifulSoup**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/4.3.2).

```
$pip freeze
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
```

You can import BeautifulSoup like this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

You can check the version of `BeautifulSoup` like this on Python terminal.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> bs4.__version__
'4.3.2'
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup.__version__
'3.2.1'
```

---

From Python Doc
[Porting code to BS4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4)

Most code written against ***Beautiful Soup 3*** will work against ***Beautiful Soup 4*** with one simple change. All you should have to do is change the package name `from BeautifulSoup to bs4`. So this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

becomes this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

If you get the ImportError “`No module named BeautifulSoup`”, your problem is that you’re trying to run ***Beautiful Soup 3*** code, but you only have ***Beautiful Soup 4*** installed.

If you get the `ImportError “No module named bs4”`, your problem is that you’re trying to run ***Beautiful Soup 4*** code, but you only have ***Beautiful Soup 3*** installed.

Comment: I now get the error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Steap.py", line 9, in 
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Then you should try `import BeautifulSoup` or `import beautifulsoup4` or `import bs4` and see which works for you first.

Comment: The problem is all of my custom modules have import errors, not just beautifulsoup.